# Are routed events weak in WPF

Tags: wpf, routedevent

Does routed events in WPF store strong reference to the handler that is attached to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the control author implemented the WeakEvent pattern then yes.  I believe the stock controls use this pattern.

UPDATE: They in fact do NOT.  Here is a reference on this and other potential performance problems:

[Optimizing WPF Application Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683(v=vs.100).aspx)

Here is a reference on weak events:

[Weak Event Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850(v=vs.100).aspx)

HTH

Colby Africa

Comment: The standard controls did not implement weak event pattern.

Comment: Oh my... I didn't know that either.  I assumed, which is never smart.  I just did a bunch of reading on this.  Here is a good reference for you on this and other potential performance issues:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683(VS.85).aspx
I apologize for the last post.